# ElasticSearch memory useage in kibana doesn't match Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I'm running ElasticSearch 6.3.1 with Kibana on a Windows 2012 R2 server with 16g ram.  Windows is reporting my ElasticSearch service is using 12g of ram but in Kibana I only see maybe 8gb allocated/used.  What is using the other 4gb of ram?

I only have one node at the moment.  Currently I have the JVM heap configured to use 7gb based on the ElasticSearch recommended ram configuration of [50% for heap and 50% for Lucene to use](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html).

In Kibana monitoring, I show 7g available for the heap, and maybe another 500mb for lucene index memory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main types of memory usage: `working set` and `private working set`. The private working set is the amount of memory used by a process that cannot be shared among other processes, while working set includes the memory shared by other processes. [Source](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-windows-memory-usage-explained/)

Resource Monitor is showing Elasticsearch is using about 8 GB of memory, the 12 GB working set shown also includes memory shared by other processes.